# Quais são as diferenças entre os compiladores IBM COBOL e OpenCOBOL?

Tags: cobol

Ao iniciar no COBOL me foram apresentados dois compiladores: o oficial da IBM, ou [IBM COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/br-pt/marketplace/ibm-cobol) e o [OpenCOBOL](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/).

Sabendo que o IBM COBOL é usado na indústria há anos, existem diferenças significativas entre o IBM COBOL e o OpenCOBOL? Os fontes escritos em uma versão são compatíveis com os de outra?

Comment: Não vou formular uma resposta porque não entendo, mas lendo o [**FAQ oficial do GnuCOBOL**](https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#how-complete-is-gnucobol): *O OpenCOBOL 1.0 implementa uma parte substancial do COBOL 85, suporta muitos dos avanços e esclarecimentos do COBOL 2002 e inclui muitas extensões de uso comum do Micro Focus COBOL, ACUCOBOL e outros compiladores existentes* - *Compatibilidade com: MF for Micro Focus, IBM for IBM compatibility, MVS, BS2000, ACU, RM e REALIA. O GnuCOBOL implementa a maioria dos recursos técnicos e declarações COBOL (excluindo Object COBOL).*

Answer (score -1):

Se estiver se referindo as duas ferramentas de desenvolvimento você vai ter uma diferença apenas nas ferramentas disponíveis por cada um dos compiladores, já que os dois tem basicamente a mesma finalidade, os códigos gerados em um tendem a ser compilados em ambos(Se as configurarações das duas ferramentas estiverem iguais). Pois tanto a ferramenta da IBM quanto o OpenCobol são apenas IDE(ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado), São ferramentas criadas para facilitar o desenvolvimento. Então basicamente nos códigos não vai influenciar nada a ferramenta utilizada. Para gerar códigos pra treinamento e estudo já serve.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).